# java convert utf-8 2 byte char to 1 byte char

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8

There are many similar questions, but no one helped me.

utf-8 can be 1 byte or 2,3,4.

<del>ISO-8859-15 is allways 2 bytes.</del>

But I need 1 byte character like code page Code "page 863" (IBM863).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_863

For example "é" is code point 233 and is 2 bytes long in utf 8, how can I convert it to IBM863 (1 byte) in Java?

Running on JVM -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 possible?

Of course that conversion would mean that some characters can be lost, because IBM863 is smaller.
But I need the language specific characters, like french, è, é etc.

Edit1:

```
 String text = "text with é";

 Socket socket = getPrinterSocket( printer);
 BufferedWriter bwOut = getPrinterWriter(printer,socket);
 ...
 bwOut.write("PRTXT \"" + text + "\n");
 ...
 if (socket != null)
 {
            bwOut.close();
            socket.close();
 }
 else
 {
            bwOut.flush();
 }
```

Its going a label printer with Fingerprint 8.2.

Edit 2:

```
private BufferedWriter getPrinterWriter(PrinterLocal printer, Socket socket)
throws IOException
{
        return new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
}
```

Comment: "ISO-8859-15 is allways 2 bytes." Uh no. 1 byte.

Comment: You are right, but stil need 2 byte to 1 byte conversion :)

Comment: What is the code of `getPrinterWriter()`?

Comment: Added, running in Java 6 as mentioned, if it does matter.

Comment: As you mentioned I can add Charset.forName("IBM863") to the OutputStreamWriter? I there any conversion? Or shall it get UTF-8 as Charset?

Comment: Well, since you write `char`s, you need to encode to `byte`s; you should specify the charset in the `OutputStreamWriter` constructor

Answer (score 2):

First of all: there is no such thing as "1 byte char" or, in fact, "n byte char" for whatever n.

In Java, a `char` is a UTF-16 code unit; depending on the (Unicode) code point, either one, or two `char`s, are necessary to represent a code point.

You can use the following methods:

- [`Character.toChars()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toChars-int-) to turn a Unicode code point into a `char` array representing this code point;
- a [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) to perform the `char[]` to `byte[]` conversion;
- a [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetDecoder.html) to perform the `byte[]` to `char[]` conversion.

You obtain the two latter from a `Charset`'s `.new{Encoder,Decoder}()` methods.

It is crucially important here to know what your input is exactly: is it a code point, is it an encoded byte array? You'll have to adapt your code depending on this.

Final note: the `file.encoding` setting defines the default charset to use when you don't specify a charset to use, for instance in a `FileReader` constructors; you should avoid not specifying a charset to begin with!

Comment: Yes, I have heard about Java allways use UTF-16 code unit. But system property file.encoding can be changed. How to understand this?

Comment: You should forget about UTF-16; a `char` has no encoding; and in fact a `String` does not have an encoding either.

Comment: I have a printer with driver who take only the old code pages, no UTF-8. He receives one buffered stream who is filled with Strings. That will never work?

Comment: Uh, are you sure you don't send it a byte stream?

Comment: BufferedWriter and its write() function. Does not accept bytes. java 6

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the code you are using? Don't forget that since this is a `Writer`, you can specify a character encoding to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test and respond in few days.

Answer (score 1):

```
byte[] someUtf8Bytes = ...
String decoded = new String(someUtf8Bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF8);
byte[] someIso15Bytes = decoded.getBytes("ISO-8859-15");
byte[] someCp863Bytes = decoded.getBytes("cp863");
```

If you start with a string, use just `getBytes` with a proper encoding.

If you want to write strings with a proper encoding to a socket, you can either use `OutputStream` instead of `PrintStream` or `Writer` and send byte arrays, or you can do:

```
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), "cp863"))
```